# Group homomorphism and group structure

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ be sets , and $H$ has an abelian group structure ( for simplicity, operation is represented by $+$ and unit is $0$).

We know that $G$ has an operation $\cdot$ and the existence of the unit $e$.

Does the following claim hold in this situation?

Let $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ be a map . If $g_1 \cdot g_2 \cdot g_3 = e$ and $\phi(g_1)+\phi (g_2) + \phi(g_3) = 0$, then 
$\phi$ is "group" homomorphism.

In other words , will $G$ have a group structure in this situation?

Comment: What are $g_1,g_2,g_3$? Fixed elements, or does that equation hold for any three elements of $G$?

Comment: Do we know anything about $\phi$? In particular, do we have any reason to believe that $\phi(e)=0$?

Comment: Note that $g_1\cdot g_2\cdot g_3$ is ambiguous unless you know $\cdot$ is associative. But ignoring that, let $G$ be a semigroup that is not a group, and let $\phi(g)=0$ for all $g\in G$. Then your equation holds.